# handle button1, button2 click in appboy

Tags: android, appboy

I am implementing `IInAppMessageManagerListener` interface and want to handle the method `onInAppMessageButtonClicked`, but I want to know the button the user pressed (Button1 or Button2) to be able to handle each one with different handling.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the button id (with [`MessageButton.getId()`](https://appboy.github.io/appboy-android-sdk/javadocs/com/appboy/models/MessageButton.html#getId()) mehtod) to know which one is pressed.

```
boolean onInAppMessageButtonClicked(MessageButton button, InAppMessageCloser inAppMessageCloser){

     switch(button.getId()){

        case button1_id:
            // do button 1 stuff
        break;

        case button2_id:
            // do button 2 stuff
        break;
     }
    .....
}
```